# Зачем нужен данный конструктор и как он работает?

Tags: c#, api

В различных программах где применяться API видел в контролерах вот такие конструкторы

```
 private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public BinaryController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
```

Вместо данного интерфейса там может быть любой это просто для примера.
Что именно делает данный конструктор? Разве это не тоже самое что просто передаем ещё один экземпляр интерфейса но не реализацию? И когда этот конструктор вообще запускаться, когда мы обращаемся к этому контроллеру?

Comment: Это внедрение зависимостей при помощи контейнера [IoC](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection). Суть в том, что есть некий контейнер, в который регистрируют тип объекта. Когда вы из него забираете нужный вам тип, он его сам инициализирует и попутно внедряет все зависимости, который тот просит через конструктор. То есть ваш код, автоматически, без вашего участия проинициализирует контролёр, передав в него уже готовый объект `IConfiguration`.